# Importing shapefile to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online

When I tried to import my data with format zip into ArcGIS Online it failed with an error message of:

> Can not import this shapefile

For details of my data as follow:

1. Has 600 records
2. In mydata.zip contain the .shp,.shx,.dbf,.prj
3. When I tried to decrease mydata become 73 records and save to shapefile, then I have success importing the shapefile to ArcGIS Online.
4. I have a student license from my university

I use QGIS just for create a layer point geometries and save to shapefile. I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You have a tag for QGIS but make no mention of how that software figures in the workflow that you are asking about - does it?

Comment: Have you asked if your ARCGIS online administrator has imposed some sort of limitation to uploads?

Comment: It's possible for shapefiles to contain invalid polygon geometries. Have you tried to validate and/or repair the shapes before upload to AGOL?

Comment: @Hornbydd i can import files with 1000 features only

Comment: @PolyGeo i use qgis just to create a layer then save to shape file

Comment: What are the precise steps that you perform to import your data, and what are the precise symptoms (especially any error message as text) when it fails?

Comment: @PolyGeo in qgis, i have a data with 6000 features, then i tried to split my data with filter and give limitation 600, after that i duplicate. After that i repeat the same steps to filter and give limitation. Then i save to shape file and compress file to zip which contain the .shp,.shx,.dbf,and prj . Then in ArcGIS Online, i just add layer from file computer, and upload one of data which has 600 features but failed with message error ' Cannot import this shapefile'.

Comment: Please include that error message in your question body.

Comment: @PolyGeo [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC5VE.png

Comment: Please always include error messages as text (rather than pictures) within the body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a troubleshooting guide available from Esri for any [Problem: Receiving errors when uploading a shapefile to ArcGIS Online, ArcGIS Explorer Online, Business Analyst Online, or Community Analyst](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011508):

> **Description**
>
> When uploading shapefiles to ArcGIS Online, ArcGIS Explorer Online,
>   Business Analyst Online, or Community Analyst, the service sometimes
>   produces an error. There are several reasons as to why this might
>   happen.
>
> **Cause**
>
> This is most often caused by either invalid shapefile packaging,
>   improper shapefile formatting, or because the shapefile itself does
>   not meet the requirements for uploading to the online applications.